# Permutations of Independent Probabilities

Tags: probability, summation, permutations, products

**Problem:**

Say that I have a list of $n$ tasks to complete. Each of the tasks have independent probabilities $p_1, p_2, ..., p_n$ of completing that task.
There is a particular task on the list that I want to get completed. However, the list will be generated in a random order and I have to complete each task in order.
Once I complete the particular task that I have in mind, I have succeeded and the rest of the list does not matter. *What is the probability that I will complete the task?*

**My attempt at solving it:**

To make it easier, I assume that the task that I want to complete is task $n$ (the task with independent probability $p_n$). I hope I'm not messing anything up by making that assumption.

I read something that basically said that the total probability of completing task $n$ would be
$$P(task_n) = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n \left(p_n*\left(\frac{\sum_{j=1}^{n-1} p_j}{n-1}\right)^{i-1}\right)$$
But although the equation seems to work for $i=1$ and $i=2$, it stops working after that point. I'm pretty sure that's because this equation is not taking into account that there is no repetition in the tasks.

Basically what that equation is trying to do is taking each possible location for $task_n$ to show up on the list, calculating the probability that you get to that task given that it is put in that position, and then averaging all of those together. That general approach made sense to me, because there is an equal probability of that task showing up in each position. So I tried figuring out equations given each position to see if I could find the pattern and extrapolate a general equation. I didn't get very far.

**Case 1**: $task_n$ shows up in position 1.
$$P(task_n, pos_1)=p_n$$
This is the most straightforward case. If $task_n$ shows up first on the list, then the total probability of completing it is exactly the same as the independent probability of completing that task.

**Case 2**: $task_n$ shows up in position 2.
$$P(task_n, pos_2)=p_n \left( \frac{\sum_{j=1}^{n-1}p_j}{n-1} \right)$$
Still pretty straightforward. If $task_n$ shows up second on the list, then the total probability of completing it is equal to its individual probability times the probability of whatever shows up in position 1. Since all other tasks on the list have an equal chance of showing up, average all those probabilities together.

**Case 3**: $task_n$ shows up in position 3.
$$P(task_n, pos_3)=p_n \left( \frac{\sum_{j=1}^{n-1}p_j\left( \sum_{k=1}^{n-1}(p_k)-p_j \right)}{(n-1)(n-2)} \right)$$
So this is where it starts getting complicated, and I wasn't able to figure out any equation for position 4 or after. At this point, I can see that I'm just multiplying the probabilities of all previous tasks, but I'm basically subtracting out the instance that the task is repeated.

I know that another way to look at this is that we're finding the product of all possible ways to choose 1 out of $p_1, p_2, ..., p_{n-1}$, then choose 2, then choose 3, ... then choose $n-1$, and averaging that all out. I just don't know how to put that into a single formula.

I feel like I'm on the right track, but at the same time the equation gets so much more complicated after this that I feel like I'm not getting anywhere. I tried looking it up because this equation must exist out there somewhere, but I couldn't figure out how to search it because if I try looking for "permutations of probabilities" then I all I get is basic prealgebra homework problems. Please help, this has been killing my brain for days.

Comment: Hi: I think you can argue ( but think about this some more to make sure ) that the total probability is (probability of succeeding given that the task is first) ( probability that the  task is first ) + (probability of succeeding given that the task is second) (probability that the task is second) $ \ldots  + $ ( probability of succeeding given that the task is last ) ( probability the task is last ).

Comment: So that results in $p_1 \times 1/n + p_2 *p_1 \times 1/n + \ldots p_n p_{n-1} \ldots p_1 \times 1/n$. Unfortunately, I don't know if that can be simplified.

Comment: @markleeds Agreed. In this case, and I suppose I didn't specify the fact in the original question, the probability of ending up in each position on the list is equal to ending up in any other position on the list, meaning that that probability is always (1/n) which is why that first equation has the (1/n) factored out. But technically yes, you're totally right about that. However, $p_1$ is not the probability that it ends up first on the list. $p_1$ is the independent probability of completing task 1.

Comment: Yes, so the position is the $1/n$ and the probability is the pseudo factorial term. Note that the second term should be $p_2 p_1$ without the asterisk but comments can't be modified after 5 minutes.

Comment: Ok, so I think your equation is missing the fact that the tasks are put into a random order. Because you would need to be summing up the product of every possible combination of these probabilities.

Comment: I think that you might be correct because the second term could be $p_2 *p_n$ say. So, if you think it can be corrected, put it down and I or someone else can check it out. The thinking part of my brain is running out of gas but I think that you have a point. Hopefully the correction is straightforward. I'm not sure.

Comment: It seems like the second term should be ( $p_2 p_1) + (p_2p_3) + (p_2 p_4) \ldots p_2 p_n$. Then the third term would have ((n-1)(n-2)) terms etc but then things start to explode and enumeration would be messy so there should be a better way.

Comment: Exactly. It gets messy really quick.

Answer (score 1):

I see no elegant simplification to the mess; perhaps some other responder will.  However, messy or not, a helper function can simplify the desired expression.

Without loss of generality, assume that you want to know the specific probability of completing task $(n)$.

For $k \in \{1,2,\cdots, (n-1)\}$, let $S_k$ denote the sum of the $~\displaystyle \binom{n-1}{k}~$ terms given by

$$S_k = \sum_{1 \leq i_1 < i_2 < \cdots < i_k \leq (n-1)} \left[\prod_{j=1}^k p_{i_j} \right].$$

Then, under the assumption that there are exactly $(k)$ tasks ahead of task $(n)$, the probability of completing task $(n)$ is

$$p_n \times \frac{S_k}{\binom{n-1}{k}}.$$

Let $S_0$ denote $(1).$

Then, the desired overall probability is

$$\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \left[\frac{p_n}{n} \times \frac{S_k}{\binom{n-1}{k}}\right].$$

Comment: I'm not quite understanding the definition of $S_k$. What are all the $i_j$ terms? I've never seen a summation defined in the manner you have here and I'm not seeing those terms defined anywhere, so I guess I'm just not understanding what's going on there.

Comment: Ok, I think I get it. The $i_j$ are those tasks that come before task $n$ when the list is generated. So this definitely simplifies and generalizes the track I was on. The issue then of course is that this has to be calculated separately for each possible permutation.

Comment: @user2661923. Thanks for what looks like a very nice answer. I don't have time to read right now but I will later tonight. It's appreciated.

Comment: @user2661923: I mostly understand your expression. nice work. I just have one confusion. Suppose n was equal to 5 and we wanted $p_5$. So, let's suppose for a moment that $p_5$ comes out in the third location. So, this means that the possibilities for what is in front of it are {1,2}, {1,3}, {1,4}, {2,3}, {2,4}, {3,4}, {4,3}, {4,2}, {3,2}, {4,1}, {3,1}, {2,1}. So, I get 12 possibilities which is $(n-1)(n-2)$. Your function is 4 choose 2 which is 6. So you are computing combinations rather than permutations but don't we need permutations ? So, still a little confused but I get the idea. Thanks.

Comment: @markleeds In the scenario that you describe, the order that the preliminary tasks are accomplished is irrelevant.  That is (for example) $p_1 \times p_2 \times p_5 = p_2 \times p_1 \times p_5.$  Therefore, there is no reason to complicate the analysis by examining the $\displaystyle \frac{4!}{(4-2)!}$ permutations.  Instead, you only need to examine the $\displaystyle \frac{4!}{2! \times (4-2)!}$ combinations.

Comment: I think I see what you're saying. Since you divide by that term, everything gets normalized so you don't have to worry about not counting in the other direction. Thanks.